# jQuery selector issue, not replacing HTML

Tags: jquery-selectors

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "ajaxClients.php",
    data: '&m=removeAlert&id='+ alertId,
    success: function(resultData) {
        if ($('#noteRow_'+ alertId).length)
        {
            alert('ROW FOUND - CONTENT IS: '+ $('#noteRow_'+ alertId).html() +' -- REPLACING CONTENT NOW');
        }
        $('#noteRow_'+ alertId).html('<font color="red">- Note has been removed</font>');
    }
});
```

So it is simple enough. On the success i do get the alert, it shows the content in the alert, etc.

Then right after when i try to set the html to something else, it does nothing. I have tried .empty(), .remove()... there are no console errors. Any ideas what i am missing?

EDIT - html...

```
<div id="noteRow_127"><img onclick="removeAlert('127')" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Remove Message" title="Remove Message" src="images/notificationRemove.png" border="0"> [04/04/2013 06:26 PM] <b>Austin</b>: afvazf</div>
```

The "removeAlert()" is what fires the ajax call...

EDIT 2...

I guess somehow this is being put on the page 2 times. Although in the PHP file there is only one instance of the function that builds the rows, so i guess i just need to figure out wth is going on there. So for anyone else with this issue, inspect the element (with chrome or similar) and ctrl+f for it and see if it is on the page more than once!

FINAL EDIT:

Since i could not figure out how it was ending up on the page twice

```
$('[id="noteRow_'+ alertId +'"]').html('<font color="red">- Note has been removed</font>');
```

Took care of it!

Comment: Are you 100% sure this exists and is part of the dom (ie not been added by some other query): $('#noteRow_'+ alertId)

Comment: Hmm, as i mentioned, the alert works and returns the contents of the row (which is a div). I can edit and paste the HTML as well...

Comment: If the content is originally a div and you are replacing it with '<font color="red">- Note has been removed</font>' what should you see?

Comment: on the screen? it should be "Note has been removed" in red, but it remains "[04/04/2013 06:26 PM] Austin: afvazf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ujimiw/2/edit

It seems to work fine from my perspective.  I just bound the click handler to the button and it works.